# Types of Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

This has been bothering me for quite some time but I do come across two ways of using select statement in SQL.

The first way is the obvious :

```
Select column_Name
from table_Name
```

And then there is a second one:

```
 Select column_Name a
 from table_Name
```

What is the difference in using the second one?

Comment: In your result set, the column name came with the alias 'A'.

Comment: Wouldn't alias be written like: AS [ALIAS_Name]?

Comment: No need for AS, it's optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version is more properly written using `as`:

```
Select column_Name as a
```

This produces a result set with one column. The column is called `a`. Without the alias, the column would be called `column_name`.

Although the `as` is optional, I strongly recommend using it for column aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Using an column alias comes handy when you want to change the table column name for display purpose, for an example think that you want to generate the excel sheet from your program that returns data set from sql server. You can concentrate only the excel generation part in your application [treat this is an common routine to generate multiple excels] and you can change your column names what ever you want using the mentioned method. Alias can be seen in below syntaxas

```
  SELECT yourcolumnname abc
  SELECT yourcolumnname  [abc def]
  SELECT yourcolumnname AS abc
  SELECT yourcolumnname AS 'abc def'
  SELECT yourcolumnname AS [abc def]
```

Comment: "*Delimited identifiers Are enclosed in double quotation marks (") or brackets ([ ])*"  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers  i.e. not single quotes which are used for literals.